# Is there any alternative of execCommand() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a JS text editor for my project. In this project, I also used execCommand() but It's actually not work in Opera Mini and UC browser for android.

So, Is there any alternative way to make a text editor using JavaScript like WordPress visual text editor.

***[Note]*** Don't suggest any text editor like CKEditor or editor.js etc.

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: Depends what command you're executing. Some have over the years received API alternatives (e.g. clipboard stuff).

Comment: Why not suggest a pre-built solution like CKEditor as you mention *since* WordPress visual text editor is also a pre-built solution? Requesting clarification here is all? ... According to *mozilla.org* `execCommand()` is obsolete ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: @GetSet then what can I do? What they used in their text editor such as ckEditor or wp to edit the dom elm? (you are also right, but I need a simple editor to make a simple things)

Comment: @WebDesigner I suppose this *I am making a JS text editor for my project.* needs further requirement details from you. You could at bare minimal use a `textarea` element. I don't know if you are trying to get at the "pretty" formatting or whatever else.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Rangy, it has some alternatives to apply classes to selected text.

Comment: @GetSet My mistake. Sorry about that. I need some features like bold, italic, link, IMG nothing else. Can you share some ideas? I have no idea to make it without execCommand!

Comment: @WebDesigner I'm afraid ideas would require *research* and as such since you don't actually pose specific requirements (except last comment), my ideas might run amuck with your design requirements. Perhaps you could research all this then post back with actual code? Although devamat mentioned something. Have that a look.

Comment: @GetSet OOK! Thank you.